# Single key shortcut to invoke Launchpad or Spotlight

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've just switched to macOS. I'm wondering if there is a way to show Launchpad and Spotlight using single button shortcut, like Windows does with Window key and the Start bar?

It would be very handy to me (possibly without external softwares..).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MacBook keyboard and Apple Magic keyboard comes with dedicated key to invoke Launchpad. The special functions are labelled on the row of function keys (and equivalent in case of MacBook Pro equipped with Touch Bar). Look for key labelled <kbd>F4</kbd> on your keyboard.

[image]

If you are using a non-Apple keyboard, go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Launchpad & Dock and select the checkbox next to **Show Launchpad**. You can also double click on the keyboard shortcut and change it to something else.

[image]

You can also define custom keyboard shortcut(s) easily by going to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts. Since you are essentially looking for single key to invoke the desired operation(s), you can do so by creating a single key shortcut (if not natively provided by macOS).

---

**Update**: Recent generation of Mac desktop and portable keyboards no longer provide pre-programmed key for invoking Launchpad. In such a case, you can define a keyboard shortcut for the same by following the instructions above. If you are running macOS Ventura, the keyboard shortcut can be configured by navigating to System Settings app → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts...

Comment: indeed the question is NOT about customize a keyboard button combination but use 1 button to launch something

Comment: I see you can add a shortcut there. I have a non Apple keyboard. My idea was to use the Windows key to show Launchpad,

Comment: @alfredopacino The Window key (also called the Meta key) is interpreted as Command key when used on a Mac. It isn't possible to use the Meta key on it's own to invoke a functionality in macOS.

Comment: well do you think I won't solve even with Autokey?

Comment: @alfredopacino No clue about any 3rd party solution. I am reflecting only on natively available solution.

Comment: @alfredopacino could you set the windows key to open the launchpad?

Comment: As of November 2022, new mac keyboards no longer feature a launchpad key in the top row of the keyboard

Comment: @Keyslinger I have added an update to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try

1. Launchpad key: <kbd>F4</kbd>
2. Spotlight: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
3. Mission Control key (bonus answer): <kbd>F3</kbd>
4. Search file on finder (bonus answer): <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

* Please note that

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> is same as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>
- <kbd>⌥</kbd> is same as <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

See more at:

- [Spotlight keyboard shortcuts on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/spotlight-keyboard-shortcuts-mh26783/mac)
- [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-pro/keyboard-apde6983e835/2019/mac/10.15.1