# Keyboard Shortcut for Launchpad?

Tags: macos, keyboard

[So this question has an answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356769/single-key-shortcut-to-invoke-launchpad-or-spotlight) (Which is f4) ... But that does not do it for me.

I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.2.1.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, if you have a trackpad, you can pinch with four fingers to open launchpad.

Comment: Pinch 4 fingers!!  Yes!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and select “Launchpad & Dock”. Click once on “Show Launchpad” and press Enter. Press the fn key and F3 simultaneously. Now you have created a new shortcut. If you now press F3 normally you will get a window overview as usual. If you press fn + F3 then Launchpad opens.

Answer (score 1):

On Ventura coming from Monterey mine was <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
[image: 'Show Launchpad' keyboard shortcut in macOS]
It collided with the VSCode shortcut for "Trigger Parameter Hints" (*editor.action.triggerParameterHints*), so I disabled it. <kbd>Restore Defaults</kbd> removes the shortcut, which shows a change from it's original default.

[image]

Comment: How is this different from the [existing answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437929/489896)?

Comment: It mentions the default shortcut and shows the UI.

Comment: That could have been proposed as an edit to the existing answer. I would accept it.

Comment: The question was ambiguous as to whether they wanted to know the current keyboard shortcut or set a new one. Each answer covers one aspect.